# Visual Studio 2019 not populating the build definition name of a TFS 2018 gated check-in build, showing <Unknown Definition>

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild

I have recently upgraded from TFS 2013 to TFS 2018. As part of the upgrade process I deleted all of our xaml builds and created them using vNext. I am using MSBuild within the gated check in.

When I check in my changes using Visual Studio 2019, triggering the gated check-in, if I view the build progress the details at the top show `<Unknown Definition>`.

[image: Screenshot]

As you will see at the bottom of the screenshot VS2019 does know the build details and the builds do work.

How do I fix this???

Comment: In the TFS 2018 web portal in Build Definitions aka Pipelines (I don't recall which version renamed them) in your pipeline in "Options" what is the "Build number format" field set to?

Comment: Build Number format is $(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)

Comment: $(BuildDefinitionName) is "HD - LIVE - Components - Gated Check In"?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: I suspect the spaces in the name may be the issue but I'm not certain and I don't have an equivalent setup where I could test. You could create a new empty pipeline and test if spaces in the name are an issue by renaming it (before touching the production pipeline). I think you are dealing with a bug in that display in VS2019 because the 'Build Summary' section is fine.